# How to connect to spark cluster with client using R

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have a cluster having Cloudera CDH running. I need to connect my R programs (running on my Laptop) to the Spark running in cluster.

However If I try to connect the local R through Sparklyr, it is giving Error. As it is searching the Spark home on the laptop itself means i have to install spark on my laptop but i can't do it.

I googled and found we can install SparkR and use R with Spark. However, for using sparkR what i have to do:

1. install SparkR on all nodes of cluster?
2. How to configure to use SparkR?

Comment: Why can’t you install spark locally? IIRC sparklyr just needs the jar files to connect to the remote cluster. Your computer does not become part of the cluster.

Comment: SparkR will need local Spark installation as well. There is no difference here.